# filter through multiple arrays and add objects from them to a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

Example of an object in the accounts array:

```
const accounts = [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603",
    picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    age: 25,
    name: {
      first: "Esther",
      last: "Tucker",
    },
    company: "ZILLACON",
    email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM",
  },
```

Example of an object in the books array:

```
const books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
```

Example of objects in the authors array:

```
    const authors = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: {
      first: "Lucia",
      last: "Moreno",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: {
      first: "Trisha",
      last: "Mathis",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: {
      first: "Arnold",
      last: "Marks",
    },
  },
```

I need to write the function function `getBooksPossessedByAccount(account, books, authors) {}` that does the following: It returns an array of books and authors that represents all books *currently checked out* by the given account. *Look carefully at the object below,* as it's not just the book object; the author object is embedded inside of it.
Output example:

```
getBooksPossessedByAccount(account, books, authors);
  [
    {
      id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950076",
      title: "est voluptate nisi",
      genre: "Classics",
      authorId: 12,
      author: {
        id: 12,
        name: {
          first: "Chrystal",
          last: "Lester",
        },
      },
      borrows: [
        {
          id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
          returned: false,
        },
        ...
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
function getBooksPossessedByAccount(account, books, authors) {
      const accId = account.id;
      const result = [];
      for (let idxBks = 0; idxBks < books.length; idxBks++) {
        if (
          books[idxBks].borrows.id === accId &&
          books[idxBks].borrows.returned === false
        ) {
          result.push(books[idxBks]);
        }
        for (let idxAuth = 0; idxAuth < authors.length; idxAuth++) {
          let authorIdx = authors[idxAuth];
          if (authorIdx.id === result.authorId) {
            return [result, { author: authorIdx }];
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you only checking `book.borrows[0]`?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to get SO to write your entire library application for you. This is your 4th question about processing this same set of data.

Comment: If you're trying to learn, it seems like you're not getting it. You keep making the same mistake, like `booksOut.authorID`. `booksOut` is an array of objects, so `authorID` is a property of the array elements, not the array itself.

Comment: You don't want to `push` anything because your end result should be an object, not an array. You want to merge certain properties from `account` and elements from `books` and `authors`.

Comment: woah woah.. slow down.. i just have one question for the dude.. you name the function `getBooksPossessedByAccount` so why do you have the other parameters `books` and `orders`?

Comment: @TheBombSquad That seems to be so that it doesn't use global variables, it's good design.

Comment: books doesn't have to be a global, but i guess it does mean that this function is not in the scope that books and orders were declared @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You need to search all the `borrows`, not just `borrows[0]`. You can use the `some()` method to check all of them.

Since the author information needs to be added as a property to the book object, you shouldn't be pushing it onto the `booksOut` array.

```
function getBooksPossessedByAccount(account, books, authors) {
  const accId = account.id;
  const booksOut = books.filter(
    (book) => book.borrows.some(borrow => !borrow.returned && borrow.id === accId)
  );
  booksOut.forEach(book => book.author = authors.find(author => book.authorID == author.id))
  return booksOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `some` should do the trick..

```
function getBooksPossessedByAccount(account, books, authors) {
  let borrowedBooks=books.filter(book=>
    book.some(borrow=>borrow.id===account.id)
  )
  return borrowedBooks //array of book objects
  //return borrowedBooks.map(book=>book.id) //to show array of book ids
}
```